# Files created when using 'sudo' command are read-only to my user

Tags: macos, read-only, access-control

I am a new Mac user who is starting to learn Ruby on Rails.  I have found that I need to use the `sudo` statement when running commands like

```
$ sudo rails generate controller home index
```

But when I do, the files which it generates appear as read-only when I try to edit them in [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/).

I did a Get Info on the file and it appears that the owner is `root` and the group is `staff`. 
[image]

Does my user `jesse` need to belong to the group `staff`?

I really just want to be able to edit my files and not screw anything up. If anyone has any guidance for a noob, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think sudo is required for scaffolding and generating, tried w/o sudo ?

Comment: You're observing normal behavior from using `sudo`. The solution is probably to properly fix whatever problem led you to use `sudo`.

Comment: @Sathya, I did try running the command without it, it was throwing some permission denied errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create files with `sudo`, those files are owned by root.  You can either:

1. Use the inspector window (the one in your screenshot) to change the file owner to yourself, or
2. Run `chown -R jesse myProjectDir` on the directory you create to change its owner (and its contents' owner) to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The group (staff) doesnt have write access either. Youll have to do:

```
$ sudo chmod a+w {files}
```

where `{files}` is a list of the files that you cant write.  Note that if you run `rails generate` again, theres a good chance youll lose +w and have repeat this.  Note also that this makes `{files}` writeable by all users, so if if you let anyone else use your computer, they'll by able to modify `{files}`.